# flutter android : fix net::err_unknown_url_scheme whatsapp link on flutter webview

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Using the Webview Flutter package, I cannot directly redirect to WhatsApp or any other link in the Webview view. Where am I going wrong? Please help! The project has WhatsApp redirection in the Web view, which gives an error in the mobile app.
I tried to solve the question by referring to similar problems on Stack Overflow, but I could not. The URLs do not work. I appreciate your solution.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class Anasayfa extends StatefulWidget {
  get keepAlive => true;

  @override
  _AnasayfaState createState() => _AnasayfaState();
}

class _AnasayfaState extends State<Anasayfa> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
    ..setNavigationDelegate(
      NavigationDelegate(
        onProgress: (
          int progress,
        ) {
          // Update loading bar.
        },
        onPageStarted: (String url) {},
        onPageFinished: (String url) {},
        onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
        onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) async {
          if (request.url.startsWith('https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone')) {
            print('blocking navigation to $request}');
            List<String> urlSplitted = request.url.split("&text=");

            String phone = "905362936408";
            String message = urlSplitted.last.toString().replaceAll("%20", " ");

            await _launchURL("https://wa.me/$phone/?text=${Uri.parse(message)}");
            return NavigationDecision.prevent;
          }

          print('allowing navigation to $request');
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
      ),
    )
    ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://www.mavikus.com.tr/store/'));

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => widget.keepAlive;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: WebViewWidget(
        controller: controller,
        
      ),
    );
  }
}

_launchURL(String url) async {
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) async {
      if (request.url.startsWith('https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone')) {
        print('blocking navigation to $request}');
        List<String> urlSplitted = request.url.split("&text=");

        String phone = "905362936408";
        String message = urlSplitted.last.toString().replaceAll("%20", " ");

        if (await canLaunch("wa.me/$phone/?text=${Uri.parse(message)}")) {
          await launch("wa.me/$phone/?text=${Uri.parse(message)}");
        } else {
          throw 'Could not launch wa.me/$phone/?text=${Uri.parse(message)}';
        }

        return NavigationDecision.prevent;
      }
```

`This code directly calls the _launchURL method with the WhatsApp URL. However, it doesn't check if the URL can be launched before doing so. This means that if the URL is not valid or if the user does not have WhatsApp installed, an error will be thrown.`

Comment: I tried but the problem still persists

Comment: what is the issue shared here